# Angular2+ | Remove forward history after browsing back

Tags: angular, hash, modal-dialog, history, forward

To be able to close my (dynamically added) modal with the browser back button, I am adding a #modal hash to my url once a modal opens. After the browser back button is pressed I listen to the pop state, check if there is a modal open and remove it. When the modal is closed without using the browser back button, I perform a history.back() and remove the modal. The side effect is that there is a forward path left in the history, which is the #modal hash.

Is there a way to get rid of this forward history?

---

I tried to navigate to the same URL after navigating back but this doesn't seem to do anything. I am also using queryParams in my app but I do not think this affects anything here.

When opening the modal, I add #modal:

```
this.router.navigate([], {fragment: 'modal', queryParamsHandling: 'merge'})
```

On pop state:

```
location.onPopState( () => {
  if(this.modalCount > 0){
    this.removeAllModals();
    const routerSub = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.router.navigate([], {replaceUrl:true, queryParamsHandling: 'merge';
        routerSub.unsubscribe();
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

**navigateByUrl()**

> Navigate based on the provided url. This navigation is always
>   absolute.

It will replace the entire Url by defined path

```
location.onPopState( () => {
  if(this.modalCount > 0){
    this.removeAllModals();
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('');         
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: I was wondering this if you do `routerSub.unsubscribe();` doesn't it mean you can't go backwards after you tried a forward?

Comment: Not sure if I am doing something wrong, but this does not solve the issue for me. Without unsubscribing, navigation completely breaks, because it keeps loading the same page on every navigation event. With unsubscribing, it adds another state to the history, ending up with 2 times the same state. And when I add replaceURL it does not remove the forward state. Also I noticed with this method, the entire page reloads, which is not acceptable in my case because a lot of data has to reload.

Comment: why are you using events.subscribe?

Comment: Good question, I thought I had to wait until navigationEnd before doing another 'navigate'.

Comment: actually if you want to move another page you don''t need that